# adding booleans (as integer)

Tags: c#, boolean

I wrote a code in AS3 which allowed me to check if a particular number of things were true...

```
If (true + false + true + true + false + true + true < 4)
{

}
```

When i tried rewriting in C#, it tells me i cannot add type bool and bool. Is the best way of doing this to rewrite it like this? Or is there some simpler work around?

```
If ((true?1:0) + (false?1:0) + (true?1:0) + (true?1:0) + (false?1:0) + (true?1:0) + (true?1:0) < 4)
{

}
```

Comment: `public int ToInt(bool b) {return b ? 1 : 0;}`

Comment: @L.B: `ToInt` exists as `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/377990/elegantly-determine-if-more-than-one-boolean-is-true

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Try using [`IEnumerable<T>.Count(Func<T,bool>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx) from `System.Linq`, with `T` as `bool`, on a **[`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) method parameter**.

```
public static int CountTrue(params bool[] args)
{
   return args.Count(t => t);
}
```

Usage

```
// The count will be 3
int count = CountTrue(false, true, false, true, true);
```

---

You can also introduce a **[`this`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx) extension method**:

```
public static int TrueCount(this bool[] array)
{
   return array.Count(t => t);
}
```

Usage

```
// The count will be 3
int count = new bool[] { false, true, false, true, true }.TrueCount();
```

Comment: Nice one! Very clean and elegant code!

Comment: That's beautiful :')
Thanks, this is just what i'll use!

Comment: +1 Yeah, nice idea using `params`

Answer (score 18):

You could create an array and use `Count`:

```
if ((new []{true, false, true, true, false, true, true}).Count(x=>x) < 4)
{

}
```

or the `Sum` method:

```
if ((new []{true, false, true, true, false, true, true}).Sum(x=>x?1:0) < 4)
{

}
```

Comment: If i were using it as a one off, this is how i'd do it, thanks heaps for replying *upvotes*

Comment: Thanks! This was my favorite approach. I had a few bools I needed to add like this, and (new[] {var1, var2, var3, var4}).Sum(x => x ? 1 : 0); worked great for me!

Answer (score 14):

Here's a more fun example:

```
if ((BoolCount)true + false + true + true + false + true + true <= 5)
{
    Console.WriteLine("yay");
}
```

Using this class:

```
struct BoolCount
{
    private readonly int c;
    private BoolCount(int c) { this.c = c; }

    public static implicit operator BoolCount(bool b)
        { return new BoolCount(Convert.ToInt32(b)); }

    public static implicit operator int(BoolCount me)
        { return me.c; }

    public static BoolCount operator +(BoolCount me, BoolCount other)
        { return new BoolCount(me.c + other.c); }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`Convert.ToInt32(true) + Convert.ToInt32(false) + Convert.ToInt32(true)`  also work in this case  i think this is simplest way we have

Answer (score 0):

You could write an extension method for the [`BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x3we7ff2) class.  I'm not sure if the performance would be any better than using Linq, but at least its another option:

```
public static int CountSetBits(this BitArray theBitArray)
{
   int count = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < theBitArray.Count; i++)
   {
      count += (theBitArray.Get(i)) ? 1 : 0;
   }
   return count; 
}
```

Usage:

```
BitArray barray = new BitArray(new [] { true, true, false, true });
int count = barray.CountSetBits(); // Will return 3
```

Answer (score -1):

(Inspired by *L.B.:s* comment) you could write an extension method:

```
static class Ex
{
    public static int Int(this bool x) { return x ? 1 : 0; }
}
```

And then (provided you include a `using` to the namespace containing the `Ex` class), you can write your `if` statement like this:

```
if (true.Int() + false.Int() + true.Int() + true.Int() + 
    false.Int() + true.Int() + true.Int() < 4)
{
    ...
}
```